# How to edit ~/.bash_profile file?

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mavericks

I am using Mac and want to edit the file `.bash_profile` using a text editor.

These are the file's permissions:

```
$ ls -l .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  55 Feb 24 12:07 .bash_profile
```

When I run `sudo open -a "TextEdit" .bash_profile` and try to edit the file the following error appears in the text editor:

> You don’t own the file “.bash_profile” and don’t have permission to write to it. You can duplicate this document and edit the duplicate. Only the duplicate will include your changes.

How do I edit this file?

Comment: For which user is the .bash_profile? Is it root or another user?

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  55 Feb 24 12:07 .bash_profile

Comment: `pwd` and `ls -dl .` please

Comment: Why is the file owned by root? Generally, each user should own their own .bash_profile (and most/all of the other files in their home folders).

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the terminal the easiest way is to fix the ownership of the file first..

e.g.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/chown <your username> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then use normal editor commands

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `OS X` to test this but found this answer on the net ([source](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1715935)):

> Because of the way `open` works [...] programs started with `open` wouldn't have root privileges. The system isn't designed to do that.
>
> [...] However combining `open` and `sudo` [...] results in `sudo` running `open` as root, but `open` still opens the application as the original user!

Avoiding `open` should work:

```
sudo -b /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit .bash_profile
```

Comment: When I did that, I got this message: `Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSWindow is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. `